# создание выдвижного блока по клику на страну. В блоке нужно отображать некоторые свойства объекта клика

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. Есть такая задача - при клике на страну делать выдвижной блок по типу как есть на ЯК
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал выдвижной блок, при клике каждую страну, но немогу понять как его теперь наполнить данными. Условно в него надо вставлять название страны.

Comment: А в чём именно сложность? Отловить нажатие на страну или заполнить блок данными? Опять же страна в вашем случае - созданный вами полигон, элемент модуля "регионы" или её нужно определять по точке клика? Пример готового кода тоже приветствуется.

Comment: сложность именно в наполнении данными. Получение стран  ymaps.borders.load('001', {...
        // Это объект regions, где ключи это ISO код региона.
        var regions = result.features.reduce(function (acc, feature) { ....... Далее объект regions добавляется в objectManager, затем objectManager добавляется в geoObjects. Информация которая будут показываться во вспливающем блоке, это описание страны (нет такого текста в ym) и он будет приходить из json файла. И тут встает вопрос,  как лучше стделать, модицифировать балун или сделать независимый блок о по id страны тнуть из базы нужный текс